# creating control array in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How to create control array in razor or asp.net-mvc3?

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? "Controls" in the traditional sense don't exist in mvc. Please provide more information so we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var j=0;
$('input[type=text]').each(function (e) {
  $(this).addClass('txt_' + j)
  j++;
}
```

You can add class dynamically for each textbox. j is the number of textbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you need input array you can do this:

```
@model List<mymodel>

for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].SomeProperty)
}
```

Comment: i want to count how many textboxes are there in the view and give them an id automatically..

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Please explain better or provide some code

Comment: i've posted the image above.. i want to create like that.. but i don't know how many textboxes will be there in my view.. i don't want to use editor templates..